# How do I clear Bash's cache of paths to executables?

Tags: bash, executable, cache

When I execute a program without specifying the full path to the executable, and Bash must search the directories in `$PATH` to find the binary, it seems that Bash remembers the path in some sort of cache. For example, I installed a build of Subversion from source to `/usr/local`, then typed `svnsync help` at the Bash prompt. Bash located the binary `/usr/local/bin/svnsync` for "svnsync" and executed it. Then when I deleted the installation of Subversion in `/usr/local` and re-ran `svnsync help`, Bash responds:

```
bash: /usr/local/bin/svnsync: No such file or directory
```

But, when I start a new instance of Bash, it finds and executes `/usr/bin/svnsync`.

How do I clear the cache of paths to executables?

Comment: stupidiest feature ever

Comment: The bash cache car crash?

Comment: @Romeno The feature is nice (it save time when you re-run a command), it's the implementation that's stupid. Bash should be automatically dropping hashes for which the executable is not there anymore.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Another scenario is that I install a new version of an executable, or change the value of PATH, specifically to use that new version rather than some old version that I tried and didn't work.

Answer (score 463, accepted):

`bash` does cache the full path to a command.  You can verify that the command you are trying to execute is hashed with the `type` command:

```
$ type svnsync
svnsync is hashed (/usr/local/bin/svnsync)
```

To clear the entire cache:

```
$ hash -r
```

Or just one entry:

```
$ hash -d svnsync
```

For additional information, consult `help hash` and `man bash`.

Comment: @Daniel It's worth adding that, in bash, you can use the command "type _command_" to find out what type of command it is - if your command is hashed, "type" will tell you. It's also useful to tell whether something's a shell builtin or an alias.

Comment: As an FYI, to change the cached PATH if running `csh`, the command is `rehash`.

Comment: The above `rehash` command also works for `zsh`.

Comment: For a more complete answer see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86012/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-hash-command

Comment: In one command selective rehashing can be invoked by `hash svnsync`.

Comment: for me solved the issue `bash: /usr/local/bin/vagrant: No such file or directory`

Comment: I discovered I was running `dash` instead of `bash` - for `dash` `hash -d` doesn't work; `hash svnsync` works for both however.

Comment: What does the `r` in `-r` stand for? I always forget this option. "reset" maybe?

Comment: I'm curious, any idea on how to do this from inside a script in a way that affects the parent shell? None of the methods in the answers work for this use case.

Comment: @flow2k It probably means reset or remove (all). Since it's a bash built-in the man page isn't so helpful but neither is `help`. It doesn't say anything but: _forget all remembered locations_. You could just guess that it means reset and be done with it.

Comment: You have 2 commands for discovering what is the origin of a command: `type` and `which`. `which` will give you the location in the $PATH. `type` will let you know the executable is hashed. If this is the case, you can run `hash -r` to resync the commands.

Answer (score 37):

There are solutions not mentioned here.

1. You can disable hashing with `set +h` or `set +o hashall`

   `help set` says:

   > -h - Remember the location of commands as they are looked  up for execution.  This is enabled by default.
   >
   > hashall - Same as -h

   ```
   set -h # enable hashing
   shopt -u checkhash # disable command existence check
   hash -p /some/nonexisting/dir/date date # bind date with /some/nonexisting/dir/date
   date # bash: /some/nonexisting/dir/date: No such file or directory
   set +h
   date # normal date output
   ```
2. You can check that a command found in the hash table  exists  before  trying  to execute it with `shopt -s checkhash`

   `help shopt` says:

   > checkhash - If set, bash checks that a command found in the hash table  exists  before  trying  to execute it.  If a hashed command no longer exists, a normal path search  is  performed.

   ```
   set -h # enable hashing
   shopt -u checkhash # disable command existence check
   hash -p /some/nonexisting/dir/date date # bind date with /some/nonexisting/dir/date
   hash -t date # prints /some/nonexisting/dir/date
   date # bash: /some/nonexisting/dir/date: No such file or directory
   shopt -s checkhash # enable command existence check
   date # normal date output
   hash -t date # prints /bin/date
   ```
3. You can bind NAME with PATH with `hash -p PATH NAME` or `BASH_CMDS[NAME]=PATH`:

   ```
   shopt -u checkhash # disable command existence check
   hash -p /some/nonexisting/dir/date date
   date # bash: /some/nonexisting/dir/date: No such file or directory
   BASH_CMDS[date]=/bin/date
   date # normal date output
   ```
4. Magic: `PATH="$PATH"` performs `hash -r`

   From [`variables.c`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/variables.c):

   ```
   /* What to do just after the PATH variable has changed. */
   void
   sv_path (name)
       char *name;
   {
       /* hash -r */
       phash_flush ();
   }
   ```

   Try:

   ```
   set -h
   hash -r
   date
   hash # prints 1 /bin/date
   PATH="$PATH"
   hash # prints hash: hash table empty
   ```

Comment: I've never understood why all the extra mechanism is supplied when PATH=$PATH works just fine.  If the PATH changes, then the PATH lookup cache should be invalidated.  Makes sense.

Comment: The use case not handled by invalidating the cache when the PATH changes is when the locations of executables change. This can be common when you are using the shell to add or remove programs, only to have it cache the last place it found them.

Comment: Messing with the command hash table is a wonderful way to really confuse someone who is trying to debug a bash script.

Answer (score 29):

To clear just one entry you need a different flag:

```
hash -d svnsync
```

The `-r` flag doesn't take a parameter and will always delete the entire cache.
(At least in bash 3.2.39 on Debian Lenny)

Answer (score 11):

As user [johntex](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/43390/johntex) has noted in a comment to the [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/5610/50855) by user [Tobu](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/2729/tobu), the simplest practical action in Bash is to rehash just your program:

```
hash svnsync
```

That's all.