# How to fix bash looking for a program in the wrong dir (Issues setting up NPM on Ubuntu 11.10)

Tags: bash, shell, path

This time I ran the "trusting" install script `curl http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sudo sh` from the dir `/`.

```
$ which npm
/usr/local/bin/npm
$ npm
bash: /home/steven/local/bin/npm: No such file or directory
$ echo $PATH
/home/steven/local/bin:/home/steven/local/bin:/home/steven/local/bin:/home/steven/local/bin:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
$ ls /home/steven/local/bin
node  node-waf
$ ls /usr/local/bin
node  node-waf  npm  npm_g  npm-g
```

It seems like some script somewhere is polluting my `$PATH`. What I wonder is, if `bash` can't find the program in the first dir it looks in, doesn't it keep looking through `$PATH`? It should be able to find it in `/usr/local/bin`!

`npm` really, really doesn't seem to want to just work. I think I'm gonna go load up a slightly older Ubuntu and give this another go...

Answer (score 7):

Chances are that you did have a `/usr/local/bin/npm` and your shell remembers it in its cache. You can [clear the cache](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5609/how-do-i-clear-bashs-cache-of-paths-to-executables) with `hash -d npm`. The cache is not shared within shell instances, so the problem will not last.

The reason the output of `which` is inconsistent with what your shell does is that `which` is an external program, so it does not share bash's cache. Use `type` instead, it's a shell built-in so it's more reliable.

Comment: "does _not_ share bash's cache"

Answer (score 2):

You can consider yourself rather lucky, because you've just learned *the easy way*, that you should not put your additional binary dirs in front of the `PATH` variable. A sane `PATH` variable in your case should look something like

`PATH=/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/home/steven/local/bin:/home/steven/local/bin:/home/steven/local/bin:/home/steven/local/bin`

But the problem that actually caused your error is not really with `PATH`, rather with *what `npm` command has probably been aliased to*. To learn that, type

```
type npm
```

Another option could be that `/usr/local/bin/npm` is just a broken symlink to `/home/steven/local/bin/npm` (but you'd learn that with the above command also).