# In bash how do I set my path so that it finds the version of a command within the nearest relative path?

Tags: bash, shell

I have multiple git repositories on my machine. Each has a subdirectory called scripts/ with a script called cleancode.py.

Using bash (really git-bash), when I run cleancode.py I want it to execute the instance of cleancode.py from the scripts/ directory of the repo that my current working directory is within.
My current hack approach is to have this in my path:

```
export PATH="$PATH:./scripts:./../scripts:./../../scripts:./../../../scripts:"
```

This works tolerably well. I suppose it could fail if I'm in a subdirectory more than three levels deep, but that's not a problem in practice. The real problem is that the first time I run cleancode.py it seems to remember the relative path of that execution and in future only looks for cleancode.py at that relative path. So if I run from the repo directory first then it works, and then if I cd to some subdir and run it again I get:

```
bash: ./scripts/cleancode.py: No such file or directory
```

because it's using the path at which it found it relative to where I was the first time I ran it.
So what can I do to get it to not remember where it last found the script? Or can I get it to remember the absolute path thereto, rather than the relative path?
Finally, is there a more robust way to deal with the issue as a whole, one that doesn't depend on adding four relative paths to my path?
Thanks in advance.

Edit: I just found [Disable bash's cache of executables in the path](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/150922/disable-bashs-cache-of-executables-in-the-path) and set +h fixes the flaw in my hack. My actual question still stands, though: what is the most robust way to find the version of a command within the nearest relative path?

Comment: No direct answer to your question, but for the case of your scripts you could define an alias that  runs `scripts/cleancode.py` from the root directory of the repository you're in, something like `alias cleancode='"$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)"/scripts/cleancode.py'`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a shell script `cleancode` in your `PATH` and do something like that :

```
#!/bin/bash

cwd=$PWD

while [ "x$cwd" != x/ ]; do
    if [ -e $cwd/scripts/cleancode.py ]; then
        # do stuff here
        break
    fi
    cwd=`dirname $cwd`
done
```

Note the `/` directory is not checked since the loop is broken before.