# Why is bash not respecting ${PATH} and/or symlinks?

Tags: bash, path

I am on OSX and installed Homebrew to get the GNU coreutils.  I wanted `gsort` to be used instead of the preinstalled `sort` command so I created a symlink to `gsort`.  My limited experience tells me that running `sort` from the CL or in a script will use `gsort`, however that's not what's happening:

```
$ which gsort; which sort
/usr/local/bin/gsort
/usr/local/bin/sort
$ ll /usr/local/bin/ | fgrep sort
1083450 lrwxr-xr-x  1 alex  admin  -   34B Mar 23 15:56:52 2016 gsort@ -> ../Cellar/coreutils/8.25/bin/gsort
1083466 lrwxr-xr-x  1 alex  admin  -   35B Mar 23 15:56:52 2016 gtsort@ -> ../Cellar/coreutils/8.25/bin/gtsort
1088327 lrwxr-xr-x  1 alex  admin  -   34B Mar 23 16:57:41 2016 sort@ -> ../Cellar/coreutils/8.25/bin/gsort
$ echo ${PATH} 
/usr/local/opt/gnu-sed/bin/:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
$ gsort --version | fgrep GNU
sort (GNU coreutils) 8.25
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
$ /usr/local/bin/sort --version | fgrep GNU
sort (GNU coreutils) 8.25
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
$ sort --version | fgrep GNU
sort (GNU coreutils) 5.93
the GNU General Public License <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
```

Notice that when checking the version of `gsort` and `sort` (when using the absolute path to the symlink) it properly shows the newer coreutils version, but just running `sort` still gives me the old, preinstalled version.  Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: Maybe try `hash -d sort`? http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/5610/70524

Comment: Related: [Why not use "which"? What to use then?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/85250)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you launched `sort` in this same shell session before installing your symlink, `bash` has cached the path-search results. Use `type sort` to check whether it answers `sort is hashed (/usr/bin/sort)`.

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't know about `hash` or `type`.