# "which" command doesn't match program being executed

Tags: path, which

I was trying to install a newer version of curl and when I ran: `curl -V`, the version number didn't change.

After running `which curl`, it displayed the path of the newly installed version: `/usr/local/bin/curl`. If I run `/usr/local/bin/curl -V` it displays the correct version.

The version being executed by `curl` seems to be in `/usr/bin`.

My PATH is: `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin` ... etc, so it should be executing the /usr/local version.

Why is the output of `which curl` not the same as the program being executed by `curl`?

Comment: Possibly related: [How do I clear Bash's cache of paths to executables?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5609/how-do-i-clear-bashs-cache-of-paths-to-executables)

Comment: Another pertinent question is https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/ .

Comment: The linked questions answered the question. There is even a question that is nearly exactly the same (not sure why the search engine didn't find it). Should the be marked Duplicate or something?