# how to update path of commands?

Tags: terminal, upgrade

i want to update the path for the conda command, which was first installed in `/root/anaconda3/bin/conda` but i deleted the directory and reinstalled to `home/me/anaconda3/bin/conda` .
but whenever i execute the conda command i get error `bash: /root/anaconda3/bin/conda: No such file or directory`, so how do i point the conda command to `/home/me/anaconda3/bin/conda` ?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5609/how-do-i-clear-bashs-cache-of-paths-to-executables

Comment: thank you , it worked, but can you tell me is it possible to change the path of executables?

Comment: So [How to correctly add a path to PATH?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the final executable has 'x' (execute access) in the permission set?

Are you sure all intervening directories have at least 'x' (search access) in their permission set?

Either one could cause this issue.

Comment: thanks for your reply, my issue was actually the package was hashed and by removing it i got it to work.