# usr/.local/bin PATH anomaly

Tags: bash, path

In Fedora 30, a `youtube-dl` problem just surfaced and I resolved it via 
`pip install --user -U youtube-dl`. 
This created `~/.local/bin/youtube-dl`.

`echo $PATH` gives ".../home/steve/.local/bin...".  
**However** executing `youtube-dl` generated "can't find `/usr/bin/youtube-dl`.

I resolved this by manually copying `~/.local/bin/youtube-dl` to `/usr/bin/`.

**Why was this necessary?  Why didn't the PATH cause `~/.local/bin/youtube-dl` to
be executed?**

Comment: Possibly related: [How do I clear Bash's cache of paths to executables?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5609/how-do-i-clear-bashs-cache-of-paths-to-executables)

Comment: @steeldriver  You were right, this solved the problem.  Please delete your comment and re-post as an **answer.**