# gfortran: command not found even after sudo apt-get install

Tags: shell-script, fortran

system says the latest version of `gfortran` has been installed when I retry the `sudo` command, but then i still get the command not found error for `gfortran`. I'm guessing it's something to do with the directory?

I'm using a virtual machine to emulate 29~20.04.1-Ubuntu. The command:

```bsh
gfortran hello.f90 -o hello
```

and the error:

```
gfortran: Command not found.
```

When I use `sudo apt-get install gfortran`, i get: `gfortran is already the newest version (4:9.3.0-1ubuntu2)`.

Comment: If you use `bash` run `hash -r`.  If you use `zsh` run `rehash`.  Then try again. Does that fix it? (Or, just open a new terminal and try again.)

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How do I clear Bash's cache of paths to executables?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/5609)

Comment: it is fixed, thank you for your time!

Comment: Interesting... so the shell hashes *empty* entries? I thought it only hashed things that were previously located (resulting in errors like `/old/path/to/file: no such file or directory`)

Comment: @steeldriver The `zsh` shell discovers executable on shell startup (after executing one external utility), and then you can force it to do re-scan with `rehash`. If you install something new without rehashing, it will not pick it up.

Comment: @steeldriver _On the other hand_, the error message would be prefixed by the shell's name, not by `gfortran`.  If it's not a shell hashing issue (and therefore a dupe), it's off-topic (problem went away).