# I have a situation in which "which -a python" is not showing execution order when run on CentOS 6 with Python 3.7

Tags: centos, python, which

Does anyone know where to begin with debugging this?

```
[chuck@vmlnx-tacx32 openssl-1.1.0h]$ which -a python
/usr/local/bin/python
/usr/bin/python
[chuck@vmlnx-tacx32 openssl-1.1.0h]$ /usr/local/bin/python
Python 3.7.6 (default, Feb 23 2022, 13:10:48)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-23)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> exit()
[chuck@vmlnx-tacx32 openssl-1.1.0h]$ python
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Jul 23 2015, 14:41:34)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> exit()
```

Comment: Did you add /usr/local/bin/python very recently? has your shell perhaps hashed `/usr/bin/python`? See also [Why not use "which"? What to use then?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then)

Comment: @steeldriver yeah, hash table shows that /usr/bin/python is hashed, but i don't know what to do with that information. i'll check out the link

Comment: I don't think you mentioned which shell you are using, however see [How do I clear Bash's cache of paths to executables?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5609/how-do-i-clear-bashs-cache-of-paths-to-executables)

Comment: That cleared up my problem. Thank you so much, I really appreciate it. If you break the comment off into an answer, I'll accept it.